# Angular route repeat the url on page refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to deploy my angular app on shared hosting, but have a problem with it. After refreshing the browser page, the route url has been changed. For instance, url is `http://myapp.com/items` after page refresh it looks like `http://myapp.com/items/items` then my app render nothing. I can't get what is the problem... Excuse me for my bad English, please.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'item/:id', component: ItemDetailsFormComponent},
  { path: 'items', component: DataTableComponent},
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/items', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

That is an apache config

```
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html
# to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

Comment: Please add code snippets or a link to the repo so I can see what the reloading logic is and determine why it's adding that extra "/items"

Comment: @a-figueroa, have added